# Script to load all models in shell - Django 1.9

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 1.9 but the below script no longer works to load models into the shell (currently used to autoload models in my IDE).

It appears that there is a new application loading system which was deprecated in django 1.9 which prevent the below from working. However I'm not sure how to properly update it.

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)-8s %(asctime)s %(name)s %(message)s", datefmt='%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', stream=sys.stdout )
log = logging.getLogger("root")

from django.db.models import get_models
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist, MultipleObjectsReturned

logging.config.dictConfig(settings.LOGGING)
log.debug("Logging has been initialized at DEBUG")
log.setLevel( logging.DEBUG)
log.disabled = False

for _class in get_models():
    if _class.__name__.startswith("Historical"): continue
    log.debug("Registering model {}".format(_class.__name__))
    globals()[_class.__name__] = _class

def debug_sql():
    from debug_toolbar.management.commands import debugsqlshell
    return
```

Revised attempts:

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)-8s %(asctime)s %(name)s %(message)s", datefmt='%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', stream=sys.stdout )
log = logging.getLogger("root")

from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist, MultipleObjectsReturned

logging.config.dictConfig(settings.LOGGING)
log.debug("Logging has been initialized at DEBUG")
log.setLevel( logging.DEBUG)
log.disabled = False

for _class in apps.get_models():
    if _class.__name__.startswith("Historical"): continue
    log.debug("Registering model {}".format(_class.__name__))
    globals()[_class.__name__] = _class

def debug_sql():
    from debug_toolbar.management.commands import debugsqlshell
    return
```

There still seems to be an issue with the logging (logging doesn't have a config attribute)?

Comment: This answer by Yunti works perfectly for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36725977/415830

Answer (score 0):

Not really solving the problem with your script, but have you tried [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions)?

Beside other useful stuff, it includes a management command called [`shell_plus`](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/shell_plus.html), which loads the models from all apps into the shell.

Comment: Thanks yes I've used that.  This script would bring similar functionality to my IDE (Pycharm) with ability to use IDE completion, syntax highlighting etc...