# Pycharm, starting script does not run

Tags: python, django, pycharm

According to [official docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/django-console.html) and [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571099/pycharm-autoload-models-in-django-console), one just has to put the code into the starting script field in settings. I have done this, but my code does not get run. My starting script is:

```
import sys
import django 
import django_manage_shell
from www.models import *

print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
print('Django %s' % django.get_version())
sys.path.extend([WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS])
if 'setup' in dir(django):  
    django.setup()

django_manage_shell.run(PROJECT_ROOT)
print("test")
test = "test"
```

After restarting the console, the app models are not available, no "test" is seen, and `test` object does not exist.

However, some of it does get run because `django` is successfully imported:

```
In[3]: django
Out[3]: 
<module 'django' from '/home/emil/GP/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py'>
```

How do I get the console to automatically run the script I put? Specifically, I want it to auto import the models.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in your code. You are using `PROJECT_ROOT`, but not setting it anywhere. Also you should import models after you do `django.setup()`

```
import sys
import django 
import django_manage_shell

print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
print('Django %s' % django.get_version())
sys.path.extend([WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS])
if 'setup' in dir(django):  
    django.setup()
PROJECT_ROOT = WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS
django_manage_shell.run(PROJECT_ROOT)

from django.apps import apps

for _class in apps.get_models():
    globals()[_class.__name__] = _class
print("test")
test = "test"
```

Comment: I used the default code from Pycharm. My post was edited to mix up the order of the code.